# How to replace all characters in a string in golang

Tags: string, go, replace

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(strings.Replace("golang", "g", "1", -1))
}
```

How to replace all characters in string `"golang"` (above string) by `*` that is it should look like `"******"`?

Comment: Can you please give us more examples of what how you would like this to behave?

Comment: ex: if i am getting a string like "INHERITED" i want to convert it into  "*********"

Comment: Do you mean `strings.Replace("golang", "golang", "******", -1)` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A simple way of doing it without something like a regex:

https://play.golang.org/p/B3c9Ket9fp

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(strings.Repeat("*", utf8.RuneCountInString("golang")))
}
```

Something more along the lines of what you were probably initially thinking:

https://play.golang.org/p/nbNNFJApPp

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(".")
    fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString("golang", "*"))
}
```

Comment: Seems the answer of icza should be set as accepted because it takes into account that string may have multibyte runes

Answer (score 16):

By replacing all characters you would get a `string` with the same character count, but all being `'*'`. So simply construct a `string` with the same character-length but all being `'*'`. [`strings.Repeat()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Repeat) can repeat a `string` (by concatenating it):

```
ss := []string{"golang", "pi", "世界"}
for _, s := range ss {
    fmt.Println(s, strings.Repeat("*", utf8.RuneCountInString(s)))
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Pitfx75imt)):

```
golang ******
pi **
世界 **
```

Note that `len(s)` gives you the length of the UTF-8 encoding form as this is how Go stores strings in memory. You can get the number of characters using [`utf8.RuneCountInString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/#RuneCountInString).

For example the following line:

```
fmt.Println(len("世界"), utf8.RuneCountInString("世界")) // Prints 6 2
```

prints `6 2` as the string `"世界"` requires 6 bytes to encode (in UTF-8), but it has only 2 characters.

Comment: Good call on the multibyte characters.