# replace all characters in string except last 4 characters

Tags: regex, string, go, replace, substring

Using Go, how do I replace all characters in a string with "X" except the last 4 characters?

This works fine for php/javascript but not for golang as "?=" is not supported.

```
\w(?=\w{4,}$)
```

Tried this, but does not work. I couldn't find anything similar for golang

```
(\w)(?:\w{4,}$)
```

[JavaScript working link](https://regex101.com/r/bxknUH/2)

[Go non-working link](https://regex101.com/r/T5ntlg/3)

Comment: you can help people help you if you post minimal self contained runnable code

Comment: Sorry, I have add links to my question

Comment: @raghzz Are you set on using regex?  This can be accomplished pretty easily without it.

Comment: @sberry Not really. As long as it we can achieve this with good performance.

Answer (score 9):

A simple yet efficient solution that handles multi UTF-8-byte characters is to convert the `string` to `[]rune`, overwrite runes with `'X'` (except the last 4), then convert back to `string`.

```
func maskLeft(s string) string {
    rs := []rune(s)
    for i := 0; i < len(rs)-4; i++ {
        rs[i] = 'X'
    }
    return string(rs)
}
```

Testing it:

```
fmt.Println(maskLeft("123"))
fmt.Println(maskLeft("123456"))
fmt.Println(maskLeft("1234世界"))
fmt.Println(maskLeft("世界3456"))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/AaUxZ2EJQW-)):

```
123
XX3456
XX34世界
XX3456
```

Also see related question: [How to replace all characters in a string in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36930263/how-to-replace-all-characters-in-a-string-in-golang/36930506#36930506)

Comment: This is a nice solution!

Comment: The for loop, incidentally, can just as easily be `for i := range rs[:len(rs)-4]`, instead of manually handling the iterator.

Comment: @Kaedys But that would panic if the passed string is shorter than 4 runes, while my solution does not.

Comment: If you do not need to worry about UTF8 characters (say, if the string is all ASCII, like a credit card number), it could be faster to convert to a `byte[]`. Probably not enough faster to be worth worrying about though.

Comment: Fair.  Then again, you could also just as easily short-circuit return if len<5.  I just don't like seeing manual iterators on rangeable constructs.

Comment: @Kaedys I agree with you. I chose not to use `range` because this looks cleaner and feels simpler to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say `inputString` is the string you want to mask all the characters of (except the last four).

First get the last four characters of the string:

```
last4 := string(inputString[len(inputString)-4:])
```

Then get a string of X's which is the same length as `inputString`, minus 4:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile("\w")
maskedPart := re.ReplaceAllString(inputString[0:len(inputString)-5], "X")
```

Then combine `maskedPart` and `last4` to get your result:

```
maskedString := strings.Join([]string{maskedPart,last4},"")
```

Comment: Perhaps I could get some helpful feedback from the person who downvoted this?

Comment: I'm not the down voter, but this solution is (quite likely) slower and involves a lot more allocating than the loop version. The regex answer is probably slower than this, but it gets a pass because the asker wanted a regex.

Comment: @MiloChristiansen I agree that icza has provided a much more efficient solution. Are downvotes supposed to be used when there is a working solution but there is conceivably a faster solution? On [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) it says: "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."

Comment: @MiloChristiansen Anyway, I appreciate you taking a moment to give feedback!

Comment: *shrug* Some people use them that way. I wouldn't, and I tend to think it is a bad idea to downvote working solutions, but others seem to not always agree.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler approach without regex and looping

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    string := "thisisarandomstring"

    head := string[:len(string)-4]
    tail := string[len(string)-4:]

    mask := strings.Repeat("x", len(head))
    fmt.Printf("%v%v", mask, tail)
}

// Output:
// xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxring
```

Comment: You could simplify this even more because you don't really need the "head", just the len of the head with ins len(string-4)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Regexp` with

```
re := regexp.MustCompile("\w{4}$")
```

Let's say `inputString` is the string you want to remove the last four characters from. Use this code to return a copy of `inputString` without the last 4 characters:

```
re.ReplaceAllString(inputString, "")
```

Note: if it's possible that your input string could start out with less than four characters, and you still want those characters removed since they are at the end of the string, you should instead use:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile("\w{0,4}$")
```

Comment: I don't want to remove them, just mask characters with "X" but last 4 and return the string. e.g: if the string is "TEST111", return "XXXT111"

Comment: re := regexp.MustCompile("\\w{4}$").     re.ReplaceAllString(inputString, "XXX")  replaces last 4 characters. How do I do it for the string except last 4?

Comment: There are things for which a regex is the right answer, this is not one of them. Sure, you can do it, but it is much slower than the "proper" way.